# create nested list from 2 or more vectors in R?

Tags: r

Say I have 2 (or more) vectors:

```
v1 <- letters[1:2]
v2 <- letters[24:26]

> v1
[1] "a" "b"

> v2
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

How could I programmatically construct a nested list like this, that contains lists of all of the combinations of my input vectors? Edit: I'd like to do this without inefficient looping structures.

```
> l1 <- list(list(v1[1], v2[1]), list(v1[1], v2[2]), 
        list(v1[1], v2[3]), list(v1[2], v2[1]), 
        list(v1[2], v2[2]), list(v1[2], v2[3]))

> str(l1)
List of 6
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "a"
..$ : chr "x"
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "a"
..$ : chr "y"
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "a"
..$ : chr "z"
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "b"
..$ : chr "x"
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "b"
..$ : chr "y"
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "b"
..$ : chr "z"
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need this in a list as opposed to a data frame?

Comment: yes, I want to use in conjunction with do.call: lapply(my_nested_list, do.call, what = my_function).

Comment: Can you clarify this? Is there some characteristic of the function that prevents it from being used with a data frame?

Comment: The function takes 2 arguments and I'd like to vary them both over a large set of combinations. Hence the resort to do.call.

Comment: the data frame can be easily converted to a list, as I illustrate in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use loops:

```
l1 <- list()
list_pos <- 1L

for (i in 1:length(v1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(v2)) {
    l1[[list_pos]] <- list(v1[i], v2[j])
    list_pos <- list_pos + 1L
  }  
}
```

**Edit**:

I think loops get a bit of unfair rep but here is some (ugly) code that avoids them:

```
l2 <- apply(expand.grid(v1, v2), 1, as.list)
```

Btw. The loop is way faster. I suspect there are some much prettier and more creative ways to do this still.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that I'm looking to avoid loops, for no other reason than to learn how to write better code.

Comment: Thanks - this produces the structure that I'm looking for. Will re-examine my assumptions about loops, too. Not sure, but I think the loop performance would scale poorly with longer vectors or an increased number of vectors.

Comment: I guess it does scale poorly but the apply functions are also hidden loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that generates the required combinations into a data frame.

```
> v1 <- letters[1:2]
> v2 <- letters[24:26]
> 
> aResult <- expand.grid(v2,v1)
> View(aResult)
> aResult
  Var1 Var2
1    x    a
2    y    a
3    z    a
4    x    b
5    y    b
6    z    b
>
```

If the data frame must be split into a `list()` of one combination per list entry, we can accomplish this with `split()`.

```
#If the data frame must be split into a list, one entry per row
aResult$id <- as.factor(1:nrow(aResult))
theList <- split(aResult,aResult$id)
```

Printing the first element in the list, we see the following.

```
> theList[[1]]
  Var1 Var2 id
1    x    a  1
>
```